# Swagger not loading - 500 error: "message":"Internal Error. URL.com/rest/all/schema

Tags: swagger

Found a couple error log entries that ***may*** be causing it. But I don't read log files very well. I can't find much on Swagger issues. Could it be the setup of Magento on my host?

500 : {"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file.

[2020-12-02 02:23:48] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://www.URL.com/admin/admin/index/index/key/6c558b5736cfb18795d1767a283cd2e99f669b3466dbb0d08ec8a1cada22b244/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BACKEND_MAINMENU"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2020-12-02 02:37:08] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://www.URL.com/admin/admin/system_config/save/key/ada8eb815031f0e8fdee95f3923a54f41b2b4a5a99b544465fc84d77d0b3ae61/section/webapi/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["config_scopes","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []

I had just created an API key when I got this error last night. Flushed cache and went to bed. This AM, still seeing it.

Comment: please check apache/Nginx log for actual error

Comment: Check all the different log files in `var/log` directory as well as `var/report`. A 500 error in my experience generally means a PHP error (e.g. syntax or null pointer exception), so check your PHP log as well. If you don't find the error / solution, post the log contents so we can see.